# Pegar o value de uma input type=text e jogar em uma variavel

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

Eu estou utilizando ASP.Net-mvc4] no meu projeto em C# no Visual Studio e preciso pegar o valor da `input type=text` que está na minha `view`, e jogar em uma variável no meu `controller`, porém não achei como fazer isso.

Eu daria o exemplo que estou fazendo, porém quando eu coloco o `html` aqui ele reconhece como comando.

Comment: Oi irmão Andorinha, como vai?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duas maneiras:

## 1. Passando o model inteiro para o Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AcaoDoController(MeuModel meuModel) { ... }
```

## 2. Passando o nome do Field como Parâmetro

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AcaoDoController(String fieldDoForm) { ... }
```

No CSHTML:

```
<input type="text" name="fieldDoForm" />
```

Answer (score 0):

A resposta de @cigano-morrison-mendez está correta, mas além disso você também pode utilizar um Helper: @Html.TextBox("fieldDoForm")

Comment: Isto seria um complementar. Esse código Razor gera a tag equivalente. O objetivo é entender a passagem de parâmetros para o Form, o que pode ser feito com HTML puro.